# How to get the value for complex object from given complex key using c#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON.

```
public class Code
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
  public string CountryID { get; set; }
}

public class Complex
{
  public Country Country { get; set; }
  public Code Code { get; set; }
  public string cText { get; set; }
}

public List<Complex> GetData()
{
  List<Complex> Data = new List<Complex>();
  Data.Add(new Complex() { Country = new Country() { CountryID = "Australia" }, Code = new Code() { ID = "AU" }, cText = "Australia" });
  Data.Add(new Complex() { Country = new Country() { CountryID = "Bermuda" }, Code = new Code() { ID = "BM" }, cText = "Bermuda" });
  Data.Add(new Complex() { Country = new Country() { CountryID = "Canada" }, Code = new Code() { ID = "CA" }, cText = "Canada" });
  Data.Add(new Complex() { Country = new Country() { CountryID = "France" }, Code = new Code() { ID = "FR" }, cText = "France" });
  return Data;
}
```

I need to get the value of CountryID from the given complex key ("**Country.CountryID**").
I have tried to get the value using the **TryGetValue** method in c#. It is doesn't work. 
I think I need to split the key and process the Complex JSON and find the nested result.
Could you please suggest how to get the value for the complex object from the given complex key?

Comment: Try using  `Dictionary<String,Complex>`?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via `LINQ` like this

```
var codeIdToFind = "AU";
var result = data.Where(c => c.Code.ID.Equals(codeIdToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Select(x => x.Country.CountryID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi HariHaran,

Thanks for your answer. My requirement is, key can't be static. It may have **Code.ID**.

Comment: @PiramaNayagam then pass a `code.id` instead of `static` field

Comment: @PiramaNayagam i have updated my answer now based on your comment